# How can I install Overpass API to query a smaller database locally on Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: jquery, macos, openstreetmap, local, overpass-api

I am currently using jQuery to make requests to the Overpass server, in order to get information about the ways that exist close to a certain lat, lon pair. However, my program needs to make multiple requests to the server and each one is currently taking around 3 seconds which is too long. I am only interested in a small area and I downloaded the extract of data I needed from https://protomaps.com/extracts My question is how to install the Overpass API on my machine running Mac OS Catalina so I can execute queries in a timely manner on this local extract of data rather than continually making calls to the Overpass server. Below is my current code for executing an Overpass Query using jQuery and Angular:

```
const searchQuery = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json]' + query;
let waysObject = {};
    $.ajax({
      url: searchQuery,
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success(result) {
          waysObject = result;
      }
    });
return waysObject;
```

Comment: MacOS is not one of the platforms that gets much testing, better try Ubuntu or FreeBSD instead. It may or may not work. See http://overpass-api.de/full_installation.html for general installation instructions.